# Content Security Policy: Blocking certain internal script

Tags: content-security-policy

I have a certain internal js-file which I want to block with the use of the Content Security Policy.

I know it's possible to disable external files, but I didn't found informations regarding a certain internal script.

At the moment I use the following CSP:

`img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`

So I'm searching a solution to make an exception for `default-src 'self'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to allow scripts from 'self', you will need to remove 'self' from default-src and implement all the needed source directives that currently use default-src as a fallback. If you set default-src to 'none' or the remaining value of 'unsafe-inline' the browser errors will tell you what you need to add.